# Are Linear Maps resistant to Noise?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, linear-transformations

Let's assume I have a $m \times m$ matrix $M$ with Frobenius norm $1$ and a unit vector $x \in S^{m-1}$. I also have a second $m \times m$ matrix $M^*$ which is obtained from the first one plus some injected noise $\eta$, where every entry $\eta_{i,j}$ comes from a Gaussian distribution with mean $0$, such that $||\eta||_F = 1/10$.

What can we say about the following expected value  $$\mathbb{E}[| Mx - M^*x|]?$$

EDIT: How it has been suggested in an answer, $\mathbb{E}|\eta(x)| <1/10$ since $|\eta(x)| < 1/10$ because of the Frobenius norm of the noise, so the equality only holds when vector $x$
 is aligned with the highest eigenvector of the noise matrix $\eta$
, but this happens with low probability, and this probability should (intuitively) change with respect to $m$
: in a higher dimensional space the probability of two random vectors having a similar direction is lower than in a 2-dimensional one.

Is there a way to improve the bound on this expected value?

Comment: What exactly is $|x|$?  Is it the Euclidean norm?

Comment: And what is $\|\eta\|$ in this context?

Comment: Sorry, $||\eta||$ is the Frobenius norm, while $||x||$ is the euclidean norm. I'll edit. Thanks for the correction

Comment: You’re computing $\Bbb E |\eta x|$ for what that’s worth

Comment: We could say $$\Bbb E|\eta(x)| \leq \Bbb E \|\eta\|_2 \leq \Bbb E \| \eta\|_F = 1/10$$ perhaps that helps

Comment: Can't we make it better? because $\mathbb{E}|\eta(x)| = 1/10 $ only if the vector $x$ is aligned with the highest eigenvector of the noise matrix $\eta$, but this happens with low probability, and this probability should (intuitively) change with respect to $m$: in a higher dimensional space the probability of two random vectors having a similar direction is lower than in a 2-dimensional one.

Comment: I agree with your intuition.  In fact, not only would $x$ need to be an eigenvector, but $\eta$ would need to have rank $1$.   For a better bound, we'd need more information about the distribution on $\eta$, though.  I suspect that there's a nice answer if the entries of $\eta$ are i.i.d. and we instead have $\Bbb E \|\eta\|_F = 1/10$

Comment: Yes i have the same feeling, but i can't find an answer. 
We may restrict to the simpler vector dot product case, where one vector is noisy. But i have no clue.